# ros-fuerte-pcl running with ros-electric

Tags: ros, pcl, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently using ros-electric-perception-pcl(1.0.2) and its addons with ros-electric. I would like to know how stable it is if I upgrade to ros-fuerte-pcl while keeping the ros version of ros-electric. I'm just afraid I'll have a lot of dependencies problems and other weird behavior of it later on if I upgrade it.

Any feedbacks..

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12843/ros-fuerte-pcl-running-with-ros-electric/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should never mix-and-match between distributions.  You'll end up getting all sorts of ABI compatibility problems that aren't worth it.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2